# Linux の USB デバイスファイルと物理 USB ポートの位置の対応を知る方法

Tags: linux, usb

CentOS7を利用しています。
Dockerで作成したコンテナにUSBデバイスを接続するため、USBデバイス位置を知る必要があります。

私が所有しているPCには前面に2つ、背面に2つUSBポートが存在します。
また、

```
cd /dev/bus/usb
```

で

```
$ ls
001  002
```

という結果が表示さました。
また

```
ls 001
001  003  004  005  006  007  008  009  010  011  012  013  014  015  016
```

の表示がされました。
デバイスの接続ためdockerコマンドのオプションで--

> device=/dev/bus/usb/001:/dev/bus/usb/001:rwm

のように指定するらしいのですが、物理USBポートと、どういった関係でパスがわかるのでしょうか？
調べ方でもご存知の方はご教示お願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lsusb` コマンドでどのポートに何が接続されているか調べられます。

ただ

```
lsusb
```

と実行すれば一覧を表示します。

```
lsusb -D /dev/bus/usb/007/002
```

のようにデバイスを特定すると詳しい情報を表示します。