# Linuxに接続したUSBシリアル変換機のデバイス名を確認したい

Tags: linux, usb

当方Linuxを使用しております．
プログラムを書くために，実験機に取り付けるデバイス名を知りたいです．

とりあえず，`dmesg`を試したところ，
`usb 6-2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB4`
と出たので，`ttyUSB4`がデバイス名だと考えていたのですが，ttyUSBはポート名みたいなものだから厳密にはデバイス名ではないと言われました．

また，プログラム内に

```
The device can be found using  "ls /dev/tty*"
```

とあったので実行してみると，以下の様な結果になりました．
一体どれが正しいのかわかりません．
知識のある方がいらっしゃればご教授ください．

```
/dev/tty    /dev/tty58    /dev/ttyc4  /dev/ttypb  /dev/ttyt2  /dev/ttyw9
/dev/tty0   /dev/tty59    /dev/ttyc5  /dev/ttypc  /dev/ttyt3  /dev/ttywa
/dev/tty1   /dev/tty6     /dev/ttyc6  /dev/ttypd  /dev/ttyt4  /dev/ttywb
/dev/tty10  /dev/tty60    /dev/ttyc7  /dev/ttype  /dev/ttyt5  /dev/ttywc
/dev/tty11  /dev/tty61    /dev/ttyc8  /dev/ttypf  /dev/ttyt6  /dev/ttywd
/dev/tty12  /dev/tty62    /dev/ttyc9  /dev/ttyq0  /dev/ttyt7  /dev/ttywe
/dev/tty13  /dev/tty63    /dev/ttyca  /dev/ttyq1  /dev/ttyt8  /dev/ttywf
/dev/tty14  /dev/tty7     /dev/ttycb  /dev/ttyq2  /dev/ttyt9  /dev/ttyx0
/dev/tty15  /dev/tty8     /dev/ttycc  /dev/ttyq3  /dev/ttyta  /dev/ttyx1
/dev/tty16  /dev/tty9     /dev/ttycd  /dev/ttyq4  /dev/ttytb  /dev/ttyx2
/dev/tty17  /dev/ttyS0    /dev/ttyce  /dev/ttyq5  /dev/ttytc  /dev/ttyx3
/dev/tty18  /dev/ttyS1    /dev/ttycf  /dev/ttyq6  /dev/ttytd  /dev/ttyx4
/dev/tty19  /dev/ttyS2    /dev/ttyd0  /dev/ttyq7  /dev/ttyte  /dev/ttyx5
/dev/tty2   /dev/ttyS3    /dev/ttyd1  /dev/ttyq8  /dev/ttytf  /dev/ttyx6
/dev/tty20  /dev/ttyUSB0  /dev/ttyd2  /dev/ttyq9  /dev/ttyu0  /dev/ttyx7
/dev/tty21  /dev/ttyUSB1  /dev/ttyd3  /dev/ttyqa  /dev/ttyu1  /dev/ttyx8
/dev/tty22  /dev/ttyUSB2  /dev/ttyd4  /dev/ttyqb  /dev/ttyu2  /dev/ttyx9
/dev/tty23  /dev/ttyUSB3  /dev/ttyd5  /dev/ttyqc  /dev/ttyu3  /dev/ttyxa
/dev/tty24  /dev/ttyUSB4  /dev/ttyd6  /dev/ttyqd  /dev/ttyu4  /dev/ttyxb
/dev/tty25  /dev/ttya0    /dev/ttyd7  /dev/ttyqe  /dev/ttyu5  /dev/ttyxc
/dev/tty26  /dev/ttya1    /dev/ttyd8  /dev/ttyqf  /dev/ttyu6  /dev/ttyxd
/dev/tty27  /dev/ttya2    /dev/ttyd9  /dev/ttyr0  /dev/ttyu7  /dev/ttyxe
/dev/tty28  /dev/ttya3    /dev/ttyda  /dev/ttyr1  /dev/ttyu8  /dev/ttyxf
/dev/tty29  /dev/ttya4    /dev/ttydb  /dev/ttyr2  /dev/ttyu9  /dev/ttyy0
/dev/tty3   /dev/ttya5    /dev/ttydc  /dev/ttyr3  /dev/ttyua  /dev/ttyy1
/dev/tty30  /dev/ttya6    /dev/ttydd  /dev/ttyr4  /dev/ttyub  /dev/ttyy2
/dev/tty31  /dev/ttya7    /dev/ttyde  /dev/ttyr5  /dev/ttyuc  /dev/ttyy3
/dev/tty32  /dev/ttya8    /dev/ttydf  /dev/ttyr6  /dev/ttyud  /dev/ttyy4
/dev/tty33  /dev/ttya9    /dev/ttye0  /dev/ttyr7  /dev/ttyue  /dev/ttyy5
/dev/tty34  /dev/ttyaa    /dev/ttye1  /dev/ttyr8  /dev/ttyuf  /dev/ttyy6
/dev/tty35  /dev/ttyab    /dev/ttye2  /dev/ttyr9  /dev/ttyv0  /dev/ttyy7
/dev/tty36  /dev/ttyac    /dev/ttye3  /dev/ttyra  /dev/ttyv1  /dev/ttyy8
/dev/tty37  /dev/ttyad    /dev/ttye4  /dev/ttyrb  /dev/ttyv2  /dev/ttyy9
/dev/tty38  /dev/ttyae    /dev/ttye5  /dev/ttyrc  /dev/ttyv3  /dev/ttyya
/dev/tty39  /dev/ttyaf    /dev/ttye6  /dev/ttyrd  /dev/ttyv4  /dev/ttyyb
/dev/tty4   /dev/ttyb0    /dev/ttye7  /dev/ttyre  /dev/ttyv5  /dev/ttyyc
/dev/tty40  /dev/ttyb1    /dev/ttye8  /dev/ttyrf  /dev/ttyv6  /dev/ttyyd
/dev/tty41  /dev/ttyb2    /dev/ttye9  /dev/ttys0  /dev/ttyv7  /dev/ttyye
/dev/tty42  /dev/ttyb3    /dev/ttyea  /dev/ttys1  /dev/ttyv8  /dev/ttyyf
/dev/tty43  /dev/ttyb4    /dev/ttyeb  /dev/ttys2  /dev/ttyv9  /dev/ttyz0
/dev/tty44  /dev/ttyb5    /dev/ttyec  /dev/ttys3  /dev/ttyva  /dev/ttyz1
/dev/tty45  /dev/ttyb6    /dev/ttyed  /dev/ttys4  /dev/ttyvb  /dev/ttyz2
/dev/tty46  /dev/ttyb7    /dev/ttyee  /dev/ttys5  /dev/ttyvc  /dev/ttyz3
/dev/tty47  /dev/ttyb8    /dev/ttyef  /dev/ttys6  /dev/ttyvd  /dev/ttyz4
/dev/tty48  /dev/ttyb9    /dev/ttyp0  /dev/ttys7  /dev/ttyve  /dev/ttyz5
/dev/tty49  /dev/ttyba    /dev/ttyp1  /dev/ttys8  /dev/ttyvf  /dev/ttyz6
/dev/tty5   /dev/ttybb    /dev/ttyp2  /dev/ttys9  /dev/ttyw0  /dev/ttyz7
/dev/tty50  /dev/ttybc    /dev/ttyp3  /dev/ttysa  /dev/ttyw1  /dev/ttyz8
/dev/tty51  /dev/ttybd    /dev/ttyp4  /dev/ttysb  /dev/ttyw2  /dev/ttyz9
/dev/tty52  /dev/ttybe    /dev/ttyp5  /dev/ttysc  /dev/ttyw3  /dev/ttyza
/dev/tty53  /dev/ttybf    /dev/ttyp6  /dev/ttysd  /dev/ttyw4  /dev/ttyzb
/dev/tty54  /dev/ttyc0    /dev/ttyp7  /dev/ttyse  /dev/ttyw5  /dev/ttyzc
/dev/tty55  /dev/ttyc1    /dev/ttyp8  /dev/ttysf  /dev/ttyw6  /dev/ttyzd
/dev/tty56  /dev/ttyc2    /dev/ttyp9  /dev/ttyt0  /dev/ttyw7  /dev/ttyze
/dev/tty57  /dev/ttyc3    /dev/ttypa  /dev/ttyt1  /dev/ttyw8  /dev/ttyzf
```

Comment: Linuxの用語だと、/dev/ttyUSB4 は 「デバイスファイル」と言います。厳密なデバイス名ではないというのはその通りだと思いますが、逆に「厳密なデバイス名」とは何のことかわかりません。「デバイスファイル」以外にどんな情報が知りたいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 7, accepted):

接続中のデバイス名は`lsusb`を実行することで取得可能です。[関連質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/31271/9820)
製品のプロダクト名称を取得するならば`lsusb -v`で下記のように[取得可能](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1901/17/news028.html)です。
`idProduct          0x0002 Virtual USB Hub`

また[udev](https://tech.nikkeibp.co.jp/it/article/Keyword/20090703/333190/)という仕組みを利用して`/etc/udev/rules.d/`以下のデバイスファイルを作成し、`idVendor`と`idProduct`を元に[symlink(シンボリックリンク)を作成する](https://qiita.com/umebosh/items/0db263bfbfa8b4b85be6#%E8%AD%98%E5%88%A5%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%9D%E3%81%AE%EF%BC%91)ことで任意のデバイス名を作成し、USB製品を繋ぎ直すたびに名称が変わることを防ぐのが一般的な管理方法です。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます．無知で申し訳ないんですがlsusb，lsusb -vで試す場合，どの部分が名称になるのでしょうか．

Comment: 単純に`ttyUSB4`など、ポートで可変となるデバイスファイル名を取り出したい場合は`dmesg`で取得してください。

Comment: 前述しましたが，dmesgを実行してttyUSB4と出ましたが，これはデバイス名ということで良いでしょうか．ポート名みたいなもので厳密にはデバイス名ではないと言われたので正しいのかわからないですが． またよろしければttyUSBのあとの数字がどのように割り当てられているのかも教えてください．